# file upload to a folder in wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, file-upload

I have use the below written code for move the file to a folder named "training".

```
  <td>
   <input type="file" name="training_image" accept="image/*" id="traing-image"value="<?php echo esc_attr( get_the_author_meta( 'training_image', $user->ID ) ); ?>" class="regular-text" />
  </td>
```

To save the image i wrote this

```
$training_path = time().'_'.$_FILES['training_image']['name'];
$tmp_file_name = $_FILES['training_image']['tmp_name'];
$upload_dir = wp_upload_dir();
if($training_path){
       move_uploaded_file($tmp_file_name,$upload_dir['baseurl'].'/training/'.$training_path);
}
update_user_meta( $user_id, 'training-image', $training_path );
```

But i could not get any result. Did i do any mistake. please help me.

This is my entire code

```
function training_user_profile_fields( $user ) { ?>
<h3><?php// _e("Extra profile information", "blank"); ?></h3>

<table class="form-table">
  <tr>
    <th><label for="traing-image"><?php _e("Upload Your Training Certificate:"); ?></label></th>
      <td>
       <input type="file" name="training_image" id="traing-image"value="<?php echo esc_attr( get_the_author_meta( 'training_image', $user->ID ) ); ?>" class="regular-text" />
      </td>
    </tr>
</table>
<?php }

add_action( 'personal_options_update', 'save_extra_user_profile_fields' );
add_action( 'edit_user_profile_update', 'save_extra_user_profile_fields' );

function save_extra_user_profile_fields( $user_id ) {

if ( !current_user_can( 'edit_user', $user_id ) ) { return false; }
$training_path = time().'_'.$_FILES['training_image']['name'];
$tmp_file_name = $_FILES['training_image']['tmp_name'];
echo "filename".$_FILES['training_image']['tmp_name']; exit;
$upload_dir = wp_upload_dir();
if($training_path){
       move_uploaded_file($tmp_file_name,$upload_dir['baseurl'].'/training/'.$training_path);
}
update_user_meta( $user_id, 'training-image', $training_path );
}
```

Comment: Can you show your complete form

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are doing it wrong. `$upload_dir['baseurl']` gives the `URL` to the uploads directory not the `absolute path` to the directory. You can't upload or move files using URL.

`HTTP wrapper does not support writeable connections`

So `$upload_dir['baseurl']` should change to $upload_dir['basedir'].

It should be

```
$training_path = time().'_'.$_FILES['training_image']['name'];
$tmp_file_name = $_FILES['training_image']['tmp_name'];
$upload_dir = wp_upload_dir();
if($training_path){
       move_uploaded_file($tmp_file_name,$upload_dir['basedir'].'/training/'.$training_path);
}
update_user_meta( $user_id, 'training-image', $training_path );
```

Also make sure that your form's `enctype` is set to `multipart/form-data` `(enctype="multipart/form-data")`

**UPDATE**

WordPress profile form doesn't have `enctype` attribute by default. By you can add that using a hook. Add this in your themes `functions.php`

```
add_action('user_edit_form_tag', 'add_enctype');

function add_form_enctype () {
    echo  'enctype="multipart/form-data"';
}
```

Hope this helps

Comment: No when i print the $training_path. I can find only the time and the '_' , but i cant find the $_FILES['training_image']['name'];. So i am confused.

Comment: @Ranjit may be you have not set enctype in your form. Please paste your complete form. Set enctype="multipart/form-data" in your form tag

Comment: It is the wordpress user profile form. and add extra field in the form.